# SimpleCursor Adapter - Cannot use this in Static Context

Tags: java, android, static-methods, simplecursoradapter

Dear fellow senior programmers,

I encounter a runtime error of cannot use this in my databasehandler.java. Is there anywhere to overcome this problem.

Main Activity

```
public class DatabaseActivity extends Activity {

    TextView idView;
    EditText productBox;
    EditText quantityBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_database);
        idView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productID);
        productBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.productName);
        quantityBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.productQuantity);
        ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        Cursor cursor = MyDBHandler.queueAll();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[]{MyDBHandler.COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
         new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rolypoly, cursor, from, to);

        listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    }
```

MyDBHandler.java

```
public static Cursor queueAll(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME,COLUMN_QUANTITY};
    SQLiteDatabase db = **this**.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PRODUCTS, columns,
      null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the whole MyDBHandler class to see how and where to get the database from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as error clearly says you cannot use `this` inside a static method. `this` refers to the "currently invoking" object, where as static is not tied with any object, you cannot use `this` in static context. Quote from Oracle tutorial:

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called

Instead of this:

```
this.getReadableDatabase();
```

You could do like this to access the `getReadableDatabase();`:

```
new YourClassName().getReadableDatabase();
```

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you for your feedback, i dont understand what does it mean by adding new YourClassName().getReadableDatabase(), could you explain more on that. Thank you.